# Set a time limit for user input

Tags: matlab

I am working on a project. A part of it requires the user to react to a figure. Goal: one has to press a key in a limited amount of time (e.g. 1 second), or the figure will close. Here is what I have so far:

```
test = figure;
tic;
pause;
input = get(gcf, 'CurrentCharacter');
reaction_time = toc;
close;
```

I have been looking all over the internet to find a solution for adding the time limit. I tried `while` loop and `timer` but I just couldn't figure out the right way. I would appreciate anything.

Comment: What's meant to happen if the user is successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop, because `get(gcf, 'CurrentCharacter')` is non-blocking:

```
close all

timeout_duration = 5; % Set timeout to 5 seconds.
input = []; % Initialize to empty
duration = 0; % Initialize to 0

test = figure;

tic; % Start measure

%Loop until key pressed or timeout.
while isempty(input) && (duration < timeout_duration)
    duration = toc; % Place the toc here to for excluding the last 1msec
    input = get(gcf, 'CurrentCharacter'); % Return [] if no key pressed
    pause(0.001); %Pause 1msec
end

if isempty(input)
    disp('Timeout!'); % If input = [], it's a timeout.
else
    reaction_time = duration;
    display(reaction_time);
end

close(test)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The ```while``` loop works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this, with some tweaking, is what you are looking for. Explanations inside the code:

```
% Let's define a control struct called S: 
global S; % We need to be able to actually change S in a function, but Matlab passes variables by value.

% Add to S all information you need: e.g. a figure handle 
S.f = figure;  % Add in the figure handle
S.h=plot(rand(10,1));  % Plot something on it  

% Define a boolean flag to capture the click: 
S.user_has_clicked = false; 

% Add a button to the figure - or anywhere else: 
S.pb = uicontrol('style','push','units','pix','position',[10 10 180 40],...
                 'fontsize',14,'string','Change line',...
                 'callback',@pb_callback);

% Define a timer object with a timeout of 3 seconds: 
timer_o = timer('StartDelay', 3, 'TimerFcn', @timer_callback); 

% Start the timer, and continue computing
start(timer_o)

% Some compute code, or simply pause(3); 
while(1)
    pause(1); 
    disp('Computing for another second'); 
end

% The push button callback: 
function pb_callback(varargin) 
global S 
S.user_has_clicked = true; 
disp('Captured a click'); 
end

% The timer callback: 
function timer_callback(timer_o,~) % 
    global S 
    if ~S.user_has_clicked
        disp('Timeout reached with no button click - Closing figure'); 
        close(S.f); 
    else
        disp('Detected user click in timeout callback');
    end
end
```