# Is there a timer for input() function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, timer

The script below waits until a user press a key ('y', 'n', or any other character) and/or the Enter key:

```
prompt = 'Do you say yes or no? y/n[n]: ';
txt = input(prompt,'s');
```

However, I like it to automatically select `n` after a certain amount of time (e.g. 10 or 20 sec) instead of it waiting indefinitely.

I was looking at [this post (Set a time limit for user input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59947369/set-a-time-limit-for-user-input) but `get(gcf, 'CurrentCharacter');`  opens a figure window, which I don't like to have.

Is there a way to set a timer for `input()` function or is there another way to get a user input (for example, where I can use a while loop and `pause()`)?

---

I'm using MATLAB R2020a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `timer()` function that executes after a specified duration, and within that function, simulate the keypress event:

```
duration = 10; % sec
t = timer('StartDelay', duration, 'TimerFcn', @timeFunc);
prompt = 'Do you say yes or no? y/n[n]: ';
start(t);
txt = input(prompt,'s');
stop(t);
delete(t);
if isempty (txt), txt = 'n'; end

% Simulate the Enter keypress
function timeFunc(~, ~)
    robot = java.awt.Robot;
    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
end
```

Comment: Nice! I was about to post this. Maybe add `if isempty (txt), txt = 'n'; end`  at the end, so the default value for `txt` is `'n'`?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, the question asks for selection of `n` for `txt` after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know `java.awt.Robot`. It works great and seems quite useful.